# How do I combine 2 .php file into one single function

Tags: php, file-upload, sendmail

I want to thank everyone for helping me get my sendmail.php and fileupload.php file working properly as individual function.  Now I am trying to combine them into a single file so the form that will use them will perform both functions on SUBMIT.

This is what I have currently:

```
    <?php
$project = $_REQUEST['project'] ; 
$project_other = $_REQUEST['project_other'] ; 
$quantity = $_REQUEST['quantity'] ;     
$pages = $_REQUEST['pages'] ; 
$color = $_REQUEST['color'] ; 
$color_other = $_REQUEST['color_other'] ; 
$size = $_REQUEST['size'] ; 
$page_layout = $_REQUEST['page_layout'] ; 
$stock = $_REQUEST['stock'] ; 
$stock_other = $_REQUEST['stock_other'] ; 
$paper_finish = $_REQUEST['paper_finish'] ; 
$paper_finish_other = $_REQUEST['paper_finish_other'] ; 
$typeset = $_REQUEST['typeset'] ; 
$timeframe = $_REQUEST['timeframe'] ; 
$budget = $_REQUEST['budget'] ; 
$add_info = $_REQUEST['add_info'] ; 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ; 
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ; 
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
$company = $_REQUEST['company'] ; 
$proj_name = $_REQUEST['proj_name'] ; 
$zip = $_REQUEST['zip'] ; 
$upload = $_REQUEST['upload'] ; 

if (!isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    header( "Location: ../pages/quote/quote.html" ); 
}
if ( ereg( "[\r\n]", $name ) || ereg( "[\r\n]", $email ) ) {
    header( "Location: ../pages/quote/quote_injection_error.html" ); 
}
elseif (empty($name) || empty($phone) || empty($email) || empty($company) || empty($proj_name) || empty($zip) || empty($project) || empty($quantity) || empty($color) || empty($size) || empty($timeframe) || empty($budget)) {
    header( "Location: ../pages/quote/quote_content_error.html" ); 
}
else {
    mail( "QUOTES@DOMAIN.com", "Request for Quote: $project", 
        "$add_info\n
        What kind of project is this? $project\n
        Name: $name\n
        Name of Project: $proj_name\n
        Company: $company\n
        Telephone: $phone\n
        E-mail Address: $email\n
        ZIP code: $zip\n
        Is there a file attachment/upload? $upload\n
        What do you need a quote on? $project : $project_other\n
        What quantity do you require? $quantity\n
        If applicable, how many pages is each document? $pages\n
        Full color or black and white? $color : $color_other\n
        What size do you want your print project to be? $size\n
        What type of page layout do you need for your project? $page_layout\n
        What paper stock do you require?  $stock : $stock_other\n
        What paper finish do you require? $paper_finish : $paper_finish_other\n
        Are your documents typeset? $typeset\n
        When do you need this project completed by? $timeframe\n 
        What is your budget for this project? $budget\n
        Additional information to help COMPANY prepare our quote for you? $add_info", 
        "From: $name <$email>" ); 
    header( "Location: ../pages/quote/quote_thanks.html" ); 
    }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Configuration - Script Options
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension
    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // Get file name minus extension
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // Get file extension
    $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size']; // Get file size
    $allowed_file_types = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png','.pdf','.doc','.docx','.psd'); // These will be the types of files that are allowed to pass the upload validation
    $file_counter = 1; // used to increment filename if name already exists 
    $company = $_REQUEST['company']; 
    $project = $_REQUEST['proj_name'];

    // File renaming and upload functionality
    if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 10000001)) { // Checks to make sure uploaded file(s) is an allowed file type AND within the allowable file size (currently 10MB)

        // Rename File
        $newfilename = $company . '_' . $proj_name . '_' . $file_basename; // Rename file as (CompanyName_FileName_DateStamp)
        // Loop until an available file name is found
        while (file_exists( "file_uploads/" . $newfilename ))
            $finalfilename = $newfilename . '_' . $file_counter++ . $file_ext; // This will be the File Name shown in the upload destination directory (currently the "file_uploads" directory)
        if (file_exists("file_uploads/" . $finalfilename)) {
            // file already exists error
            echo "This file already exists. Please rename this file and upload again if necessary."; 
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "file_uploads/" . $finalfilename); 
            echo "File uploaded successfully."; 
        } 
    }   elseif (empty($file_basename)) {
            // file selection error
            echo "Please select a file to upload."; 
        } elseif ($filesize > 10000000) {
            //file size error
            echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large. Files must be no larger than 10MB."; 
        } else {
            // file type error
            echo "The file you attempted to upload is not allowed. You can only upload the following types of files: .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx, and .psd."; 
            unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); 
        }
    }
    /* 
    must add page links for error and success messages: 
    // redirect to upload success url
     header( "Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html" );
    die();
    */

    ?>
```

The "sendmail" portion works and I get the answers to my form inputs emailed to me clearly and concisely.  However, since I added the "file_upload" file into bottom of the sendmail.php with no changes to either (just cut and pasted in above the final closing php tag ?>), the file_upload and renaming functions do not work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to get this to work in a single file? I am less than new to php but any thoughts/assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Define "do not work". What errors do you get?

Comment: Sorry @ceejayoz.  I get no errors.  The info from the form gets sent to my email formatted as expected but the file is not uploaded to my server.  No errors are shown.  So it seems like the file "works" but is not following through with the file_upload part of the function. I am less than new with php so I don't even know where to begin with troubleshooting.  It seems like the function stops before it even gets to the file rename and upload portion.

Answer (score 0):

Your form obviously posts a submit value right? If not it will skip the file upload function.

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="TRUE" />
```

Because you put this at the top of the file_upload portion of the script.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

The other thing could be you moved the file_upload.php file from one directory to another and now when you call

```
file_exists( "file_uploads/" . $newfilename)
```

The directory can not be found and skips the function.

Last, are you missing a {} for the while loop? You said you copied 100% from another file. So im assuming it worked like this when it was on it's own?

```
while (file_exists( "file_uploads/" . $newfilename ))
```

Comment: yes my form does have a SUBMIT input. You can view the sample short form here: http://www.niagarathistle.com/upload/form_upload.html I commented out the php that throws an error if certain field are let blank so I didn't have to recreate the entire form. The file_uploads directory is still in the same place as originally. I tried adding the curly braces {} you suggested, but that did nothing but throw a syntax error.  The original file_upload.php file did not have those braces.  Any thought?

Comment: Anyone have any further ideas on why this isn't uploading and renaming the file as intended?

Comment: If i can get some time free. I will take a look at your link and code again. No promises. ;)